# Zonal statistics over Trend Raster

Tags: r, zonal-statistics

I have a raster containing Mann-Kendall trend values and p-values for each pixel. Essentially, I possess both the magnitude of the trend and the corresponding significance level per pixel. I aim to summarize this information within a specific area using zonal statistics.

I considered setting all non-significant values (p < 0.05) to 0, but this would alter the mean. So  I opted to disregard the p-values, and just summarize the trend data.

Should I calculate the mean and standard deviation while disregarding the p-values of the trend, or how should I incorporate them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question is mostly related to statistics rather GIS. You can ask in [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You have tags for QGIS, ArcGIS Desktop and R but do not tell us which single software you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: It can be either sofware. I did the trend calculations in R and the zonal statistics in R. Thanks for your anwers.

Comment: If you choose to ask about R then please include code to illustrate what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.